# Socket programming on java and android

Tags: java, android, sockets

```
s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(server_address), server_port);
out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

...

out.println("DESCRIBE " + url + " RTSP/1.0");
out.println("CSeq: 1");
out.println("");

String answer = null;
try {
    answer = in.readLine();
...
```

If it happen in java project all good and we get answer like "RTSP/1.0 200 OK\n", but if I run same code on android I haven't any response.
Why?

Comment: Any exceptions shown in logcat?

Comment: No, logcat haven't any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also `println()` isn't good enough. You have to send exactly \r\n as line terminators for most Internet protocols, not whatever your local system's line terminator is.

Answer (score 0):

My guess without you giving any kind of error messages is that you need to add the [Internet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your app.